# How can I minimize crumbliness in agar based candies?

Tags: candy

3.5% agar agar makes a sturdy gel, which can be [used to make candy](http://wendyinkk.blogspot.com/2010/02/dried-agar-agar-jelly-candy.html).
However, instead of dissolving smoothly in the mouth, the agar tends to break down into small chunks.
Would adding a percent or two of gelatin add meltiness, or is there some other additive that is commonly used to improve mouth feel in candies of this type?

April 12 Update: Tried various combinations of Agar with gelatin, glycerol, xanthan gum, tapioca flour.
3% agar with 2.5% tapioca was least crumbly, but still not great.
Tapioca alone is pretty sticky stuff, and **not** suitable for pressing into molds, but with the addition of glycerol to keep it from hardening it can be made into blobs of vaguely palatable candy that don't crumble in your mouth.

Comment: The link you referenced IS using gelatin to make gummy candies(which is typically the ingredient to make the gummy candies). Can you maybe post the link to the candy recipe you are using that contains the agar agar?

Comment: @Jay Oops, fixed. Basically just dissolving up agar to 3.5%, adding sugar, color, flavor, pour and let solidify.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look here http://blog.khymos.org/recipe-collection/ but i see no recipe that fixes agar's crumbliness. All the candy recipes use gelatin or cornstarch.